# PHP Class How to output this method

Tags: php, class, methods

Hi as I mentioned in last question that I am learning class and method in php so I have another problem to understand how to use this query method to output the result in theme.

I am trying with WordPress at the moment so please consider it. However it is not too generic with WordPress rather the logic.

```
<?php

class get_user_widget
{

    // other mentods are here which is not related to below method

    public static function get_users() {
        global $wpdb;        

        $query = "SELECT id, user_login FROM $wpdb->users ORDER BY user_registered DESC";
        $users = $wpdb->get_results($query);

        // here I am using foreach so is it okay or while loop is right to use?
        foreach ($users as $users)
            $rs[] = $users;

        return count($rs) ? $rs : array();

    }

}

?>
```

So how can I use this in theme to render the output list of user by registered date? I have checked with print_r() and connection and everything is fine and getting output in array but need to use html.

Thanks a lot..

Comment: I think you need to read the PHP manual if you don’t know how to take the output of a function and render it as HTML.

Comment: I know how to output the function but as I never worked with class and method so it is bit confusing to me to how to get output as a each single item using above method. Rest I can manage.

Comment: Have you tried `echo get_user_widget::get_users();`?

Comment: And I think you should read the OOP manual. This is not OO but just a class.

Comment: @Stefan Yes but it is giving `Array` as output. My question is exactly that how to convert this array in to single item. Confuse as in method already foreach. I would appreciate if someone can provide few minutes to write the login which can help me to understand what's going on.. thanks a lot

Comment: @jordi12100, I think not every one is a masters right? and I think if all experts think that beginner should refer something than please at least post some reference links too. That will be highly appreciated.

Comment: post the output of print_r(get_user_widget::get_users()) please

Comment: @Stefan thanks again. Yes I am getting output in array format from the beginning.

Comment: then post this output in some shortened form

Comment: Sorry! here is the output I get `Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 3 [user_login] => jackd ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 2 [user_login] => rahul ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 1 [user_login] => admin ) )`

Comment: @pixelngrain Google will give you lots of results (query:PHP OOP Tutorial). Like this one: http://www.killerphp.com/tutorials/object-oriented-php/ and this one: http://webhole.net/2010/04/17/10-object-oriented-php-tutorials/

Comment: @jordi12100 thanks a lot. truly I have been reading and watching tutorials since few weeks and learn few things too. (thanks to all authors) but somehow my base is still not clear and may need more guidance and practice... thanks again I really appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class can be used like this:

```
$array = get_user_widget::get_users();
echo "<ul>";
foreach($array as $user) {
echo "<li>".$user->user_login."</li>";
}
echo "</ul>";
```

EDIT:

```
class get_user_widget
{

    public static function get_users() {
        global $wpdb;        

        $query = "SELECT id, user_login FROM $wpdb->users ORDER BY user_registered DESC";
        $users = $wpdb->get_results($query);


        if(!empty($users)) {
             return $users;
        }
        else {
             $fakeuser = new stdClass();
             $fakeuser->user_login = "No users in database";
             return array($fakeuser);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This is just wonderful and what I want to learn. If you have few more minutes can you please explain logically connection between method and this code how it works.

As I understand you called the method and assign to the `$array` and   than used foreach to get single item. But is this foreach the same what is in method? or there is no relation between method's foreach and theme foreach?

Comment: The foreach you have in your class is actually senseless because it just copies $users to $rs and then the method returns $rs. The foreach loop above is only used to wrap the raw data in <li> tags.

Comment: So I can/should remove foreach from class?

Comment: have a look at my updated answer and see if it works for you.

Comment: now this is call expert touchup. the code is perfectly working. See I never thought to make function in this way. Million thanks.